# Condition for overflow in google guava library

Tags: math, overflow, guava, integer-arithmetic, underflow

This is the code for LongMath.checkedAdd() method which throws Arithmetic exception on overflow or underflow.

```
public static long checkedAdd(long a, long b) {
  long result = a + b;
  checkNoOverflow((a ^ b) < 0 | (a ^ result) >= 0);
  return result;
}

static void checkNoOverflow(boolean condition) {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("overflow");
  }
}
```

I understand why this API is testing for (a ^ result) but I don't understand the reason to include this condition : (a ^ b) < 0 . How does testing that the numbers are of opposite signs help?

Comment: If `a` and `b` are of opposite signs then *addition* of them cannot possibly overflow.

Comment: You are right, I was missing the ! in condition for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GregS wrote, If `a` and `b` are of opposite signs(*) then addition of them cannot possibly overflow. Now, if they're of the same sign, the sign of the result must be the same if there's mo overflow.

---

(*) With zero and positive treated the same, which doesn't matter and makes the condition simple.